# Change order status when switching subscription products

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, woocommerce-subscriptions

I'm using WooCommerce and Subscriptions. When customers switch the items in its subscription they go through the entire order process again and the order status is set to Processing/Completed. I wanted to change the order status to `Switch order`. But my problem is I don't know what data I'm going to use to target only switch subscription orders.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'thankyou_change_order_status_to_switch' );

function thankyou_change_order_status_to_switch( $order_id ){
   if( ! $order_id ) return;

   $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );


    if ( $order->has_status( 'processing' ) ) {          
       $order->update_status( 'switch-order' );     
    }           
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solved the problem. Here is the code.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'thankyou_change_order_status_to_switch' );

function thankyou_change_order_status_to_switch( $order_id ){
   if( ! $order_id ) return;

   $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

if( wcs_order_contains_subscription( $order, 'switch' ) && $order->has_status( 'processing' ) ){

    $subscriptions = wcs_get_subscriptions_for_order( $order_id );
    foreach( $subscriptions as $subscription_id => $subscription ){                     
            $order->update_status( 'switch-order' );
    }
}   

}
```

I don't think this line of codes is still needed.

```
    $subscriptions = wcs_get_subscriptions_for_order( $order_id );
    foreach( $subscriptions as $subscription_id => $subscription ){}
```